# Possible Threading Issue in 0.9.3 for Scenario Outline Using Runner

Tags: karate

I noticed an overnight Jenkins job had a failure in Junit report, but not in Cucumber.  Looking at the logs I see the same call was made twice, one failing for a socket exception timeout, and the other passing.
We're still using Junit4.

From the job log in Jenkins:

```
00:40:23.954 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - request:
1 > GET https://qa.api.company.com/account/v1/accounts/12345/obligations?pageNumber=1&pageSize=20000
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > Host: qa.api.company.com
1 > SourceApplicationName: integrationTest
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/11.0.3)
1 > api-key: xxxx

00:40:26.012 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5] ERROR com.intuit.karate - java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out, http call failed after 2058 milliseconds for URL: https://qa.api.company.com/account/v1/accounts/12345/obligations?pageNumber=1&pageSize=20000
00:40:26.012 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5] ERROR com.intuit.karate - http request failed: 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

```
00:46:08.259 [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-7] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - request:
1 > GET https://qa.api.company.com/account/v1/accounts/12345/obligations?pageNumber=1&pageSize=20000
```

From the Cucumber Report:

```
00:46:08.259 request:
1 > GET https://qa.api.company.com/account/v1/accounts/12345/obligations?pageNumber=1&pageSize=20000
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > Host: qa.api.republicservices.com
1 > SourceApplicationName: integrationTest
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/11.0.3)
1 > api-key: masked

00:46:09.144 response time in milliseconds: 107.94
1 < 200
```

The one thing I can think of is we're extending a "master" runner:

```
public class AccountsRunner extends IntegrationRunner {

    @Test
    public void accountsRunner() {
        Results results = Runner.parallel(getClass(), 5);
```

Master runner:

```
@KarateOptions(tags = {"~@ignore"}, features = "classpath:tests/")
public class IntegrationRunner {

    @Test
    public void integrationRunner() {
        Results results = Runner.parallel(getClass(), 5);
```

Not sure if extending the runner is causing the problem, or this is a threading issue in Karate, but I wouldn't expect a scenario to run in more than one pool.

Answer (score 0):

This may be fine because the apache http client has a habit of re-trying a failed request for up to 3 times.

Comment: I think it was due to the way we extended the `IntegrationRunner`.  Going with that as our only runner seems to clear up the problem.